# Emission light not working in blender 2.93.2 (cylces)

Tags: emission

I want to make an UV Sphere glow.
I try to achieve it with the following nodes:
[image: Nodes for glowing effect]

When I render the image in cycles I dont see the glowing effect:
[image: rendered image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycles/Eevee are 2 very different renders in case of emission lighting, If you want your circle to glow it may be easier to set render engine to Eevee and check Bloom settings.

If however, you wish to use Cycles, then you need to add glow in composition like this:
[image]

You can try different settings but Fog Glow should give you the bloom effect, other values such as mix, threshold, size etc are changing the size/strength of the glowing effect (this is the only way in cycles to add glow because of what Cycles is

No composition:
[image]

with composition:
[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you very much!